# SBJson parse attempt -- objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sbjson

I'm trying to parse the following JSon (which was validated I think last time I checked):

```
{
    "top_level" =     (
                {
            "download" = "http:/target.com/some.zip";
            "other_information" = "other info";
            "notes" =             (
                                {
                    obj1 = "some text";
                    obj2 = "more notes";
                    obj3 = "some more text still";
                }
            );
            title = "name_of_object1";
        },
                {
            "download" = "http:/target.com/some.zip";
            "other_information" = "other info";
            "notes" =             (
                                {
                    obj1 = "some text";
                    obj2 = "more notes";
                    obj3 = "some more text still";
                }
            );
            title = "name_of_object2";
        },
                {
            "download" = "http:/target.com/some.zip";
            "other_information" = "other info";
            "notes" =             (
                                {
                    obj1 = "some text";
                    obj2 = "more notes";
                    obj3 = "some more text still";
                }
            );
            title = "name_of_object3";
        }
    );
}
```

My attempt is using the following:

```
NSDictionary *myParsedJson = [myRawJson JSONValue];

for(id key in myParsedJson) {
    NSString *value = [myParsedJson objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(value);
}
```

Error:

```
-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6bb7b40
```

**Question:**
It seems to me that JSon value makes myParsedJson object an NSArray instead of a NSDictionary.

How would I iterate through the objects called name_of_object and access each of the nested dictionaries? Am I going about it the right way?

Comment: Jesse having already given what I think is the correct answer, I'll make the standard indirectly related comment: since iOS 5 Apple have supplied a built-in JSON parser; you're probably using it for a good reason but don't expect SBJSON parser to be well supported in the future.

Comment: oh thanks Tommy; I wasn't aware of that at all.

Comment: @Tommy, what makes you think that? I am the author of SBJson and have no intention to stop supporting it.

Comment: @StigBrautset simple speculation about usage; you'll be seeing significantly lower uptake now as your work — great though it is — no longer has a strong use case. When projects are no longer so vital most authors will reinvest their talent in a new project. You're obviously a talented person so my speculation was that you'll be more likely to focus on something people are more likely to use.

Comment: @Tommy granted, but then it's pretty mature by now and doesn't actually require much effort to maintain. Additionally it has features which Apple's parser does not, so it still has a place even on iOS 5 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of NSLog must be a string. Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", value);
```

Comment: but it's already a string since value refers to an nsstring object?.... (some time later after running it... and it actually working) wait... why do i need to cast a string into a string?

Comment: This is not a cast.  NSLog accepts a *format* string, not a string variable.  Also `%@` does not mean "string" either.  It means "object"

Comment: Just to clarify @borrrden's statement: it's perfectly fine to keep a format string in a variable, but it is unsafe to not use one if you attempt to print data you don't control, as someone could craft a format string that would crash your app.

Answer (score 1):

Your `value` is not a string, just because you've typed it so.
Based on the structure you posted you will have an array as your
top-level object.

```
NSDictionary *myParsedJson = [myRawJson JSONValue];
for(id key in myParsedJson) {
    id value = [myParsedJson objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
}
```

The `%@` syntax in NSLog causes the `-description` method to be
called on value; this method returns an NSString. That means
that you *could* do `NSLog([value description]);` but this is
generally not a good idea. (Someone could craft malicious input that could crash your app.)